# Mellin Transform and Analytic parts of the Zeta function

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, riemann-zeta-function, several-complex-variables

Suppose I had this transform

\begin{equation}
\zeta(s) = \dfrac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

for $0\le\Re(s)\le 1$. If we write $$\Gamma(s) = \alpha_1(s) +\beta_1(s) i$$ and $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx} = \alpha_2(s)+\beta_2(s)i$$ with these expressions also holding for $0\le\Re(s)\le 1$. Then we can write

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\zeta(s) & = \dfrac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx}\\
  & = \dfrac{\biggl[\alpha_1(s)-\beta_1(s) i\biggr]\biggl[\alpha_2(s)+\beta_2(s)i\biggr]}{\alpha_1(s)^2+\beta_1(s)^2}\\
& = \dfrac{\alpha_1(s)\alpha_2(s)+ \alpha_1(s)\beta_2(s)i- \beta_1(s)\alpha_2(s)i+\beta_1(s)\beta_2(s)}{\alpha_1(s)^2+\beta_1(s)^2}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

So we can see $\zeta(s)= 0$ depends on the solution to the equation

\begin{equation}
\alpha_1(s)\alpha_2(s)+ \alpha_1(s)\beta_2(s)i- \beta_1(s)\alpha_2(s)i+\beta_1(s)\beta_2(s) = 0 , ~~~~ \alpha_1(s)^2+\beta_1(s)^2\neq 0
\end{equation}

which happens when $\alpha_1(s)\neq 0\neq \beta_1(s) $(otherwise this point might produce singularity). Is this a valid expression for $\zeta(s)$ in the half plane and what is a possible easy method to find the roots of this complex equation involving $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\beta_1,\beta_2)$?

Comment: From a computational viewpoint, approximating the $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ in order to find zeros of $\zeta(s)$ do not seem like a computationally easier task than other possible methods, like the most immediate one that comes to mind which involves contour integration. From a theoretical viewpoint, understanding zeros of $\alpha_2(s)$ doesn't seem much easier than understanding zeros of $\zeta(s)$, or those of a more complicated expression involving the $\beta_i(s)$'s.

Comment: @kindasorta never mind lol

Comment: its still complex lol but the last equation shows something

Comment: @kindasorta no they are real valued functions I am right the way i wrote it confused myself

Comment: basically I found expression for the roots of $\zeta(s)$ in the half plane in terms of the analytic components of gamma function ( and the other function) and which I don't have yet @kindasorta if you can tell me maybe you can help me here. Can you see if there is easy formula for $\Re(\Gamma) = \alpha_1$ and $\Im(\Gamma) = \beta_1$ for $0\le \Re(s)\le 1$.